# C# dashed lines in chart series?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm using the Chart control from .net 4.0 in my C# WinForms app.
I have two series' of data displayed as line graphs.

I'm graphing basically a supply and demand as a function of time.
I want the demand to be a solid line of some colour, and the supply to be a dashed line of the same colour.

I can set the colour fine, but I can't find anywhere where I can set the line style to be dashed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See the [`DataPointCustomProperties.BorderDashStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.borderdashstyle.aspx) property.  For example...

```
_chart.Series[1].Color = Color.Blue;

_chart.Series[0].Color = Color.Blue;
_chart.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
_chart.Series[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

...gives me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Who'd have thunk that what should have been called Series.LineDashStyle is actually called Series.BorderDashStyle!

Comment: why can't I use BorderDashStyle? I have `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` added to the project

Answer (score 5):

This changes slightly with Visual Studio 2010's version of chart control:

`this.chart1.Series["Data1"].BorderDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;`

Comment: Note that [`Chart.Series[string name]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456421) is only a complementary indexer. [`Chart.Series[int index]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434) remains available, so Chris's answer is completely valid in _.NET 4_ as well.

Comment: why am I not seeing `BorderDashStyle `?

Comment: Is there any way of shortening `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash`?

Comment: If you put `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` at the top of the .cs file, you can then shorten it to `ChartDashStyle.Dash`.