# Can I draw dashed lines in WPF Toolkit chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, mschart

In my WPF based application, I am using the Data Visualization Charting component available in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/). I want to draw dashed lines, similar to the illustration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011854/650012) SO answer:

[image: Solid and dashed lines]

Unfortunately, this only works with Windows Forms, since the [BorderDashStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.borderdashstyle) property only exists in the Windows Forms version of the *DataVisualization.Charting* component and not in the WPF Toolkit equivalent.

How should I go about to generate dashed lines with the *WPF Toolkit* charting component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for an analogous solution for the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) charting component, and found [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/86366.aspx/1).

Luckily, it turns out that the same approach can be applied in WPF. By setting the property `LineSeries.PolylineStyle` to a `System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline` style with a suitable `Shape.StrokeDashArray` property setting, the desired line dash can be obtained.

Programmatically, it can be accomplished with something like this:

```
var series = new LineSeries
    {
         ItemsSource = calcData,
         IndependentValuePath = "X",
         DependentValuePath = "Y",
         PolylineStyle = GetDashedLineStyle()
    };

...

Style GetDashedLineStyle()
{
    var style = new Style(typeof(Polyline));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Shape.StrokeDashArrayProperty, 
                      new DoubleCollection(new[] { 5.0 })));
    return style;
}
```

Comment: Useful - thanks for answering your own question! I also used this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/RoundStrokeDashCapPolyline.htm)

Comment: after 3 hours of searching found this. Thank you.. Copied from the link referenced above
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                               DependentValuePath="Value"
                               IndependentValuePath="Key">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 3 2" />
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add to xaml in WPF :

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

...


    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DashedPolyLine" TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">                        
            <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 3 2" />
        </Style>        
    </Window.Resources>

...

<chartingToolkit:LineSeries  Title="Title" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingValue}" PolylineStyle="{StaticResource DashedPolyLine}"/>
```